# Como pasar valores a un PHP en una misma pagina y mantenerlos seleccionado

Tags: php, html

en este caso estoy enviando valores( de un select y de un numero), los valores pasan normalmente, pero el problema es que cuando seleeciono uno, se deseleciona el otro, pero lo que yo quisiera es que se queden seleccionados(si es que seleccione los dos), como podria hacer para que cuando seleccione un valor, se quede marcado en su select.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h2>Pasar Valores</h2>
 <form action="buscar.php">
    <select name="miselector" id="miselector" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="">seleccionar</option>
        <option value="coches">coches</option>
        <option value="casas">casas</option>
    </select>

  <input type="Number" name="semana" id="semana" style="width: 50px; height: 25px; text-align: center;position: center" step="1">
  </form>

   <?php
     if (isset($_GET['miselector']) or isset($_GET['semana'])) {
       echo "<br>estado: ".$_GET["miselector"];
       echo "<br>semana: ".$_GET["semana"];
     }
   ?>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes agregar JS para resolver este caso, por ejemplo el siguiente caso

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h2>Pasar Valores</h2>
 <form action="index.php">
    <select name="miselector" id="miselector" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="">seleccionar</option>
        <option value="coches">coches</option>
        <option value="casas">casas</option>
    </select>

  <input type="Number" name="semana" id="semana" style="width: 50px; height: 25px; text-align: center;position: center" step="1">
  </form>

   <?php
     if (isset($_GET['miselector']) or isset($_GET['semana'])) {
       echo "<br>estado: ".$_GET["miselector"];
       echo "<br>semana: ".$_GET["semana"];
     }
   ?>
</body>

<script>
document.getElementById("miselector").value = "<?php echo($_GET["miselector"]);?>";
document.getElementById("semana").value = "<?php echo($_GET["semana"]);?>";
</script>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

En ese caso, deberías usar un [select multiple](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_select_multiple.asp), y aquí sí haría falta un botón para enviar el formulario (los valores seleccionados) para poder leerlos desde php, ya que de otra forma, se ejecutará el evento onchange en cuanto selecciones el primer elemento de tu select.

Este [ejemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple) es muy claro.